# how to flush output of diff

Tags: unix, diff, ksh

I have script something like this

```
diff abc def

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then          

    make modules_install

enif
```

How i can avoid ouput of diff

if I do `diff abc def 2 >/dev/null` then still ouput display.

Any idea ?

Comment: It was simple just to do diff abc def >/dev/null

Comment: You shouldn't need to use diff to decide if you're going to run make. the `make` command is designed to test all components of a final build target to see if the components are up-to-date. If any are new, make will control rebuilding the smallest set of code needed to bring the final object up-to-date. You have use a makefile to tell make what are the dependencies. Look at gmake doc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You must redirect stdout and stderr.  You can use the following:

```
diff abc def > /dev/null 2>&1 && make modules_install
```

If you need to do more than one thing when the files are the same, then the if statement would be better:

```
if diff abc def > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  make modules_install
fi
```

NOTE: When the exit code of the command is 0 it is seen as true for tests in the shell.